# Lambda Expression with Inner Lambda Expression

Tags: c#, .net, lambda, closures

```
The type or namespace name 'c' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

I'get the error from above when I try to run the code from below.

```
this.Calendar.Entries.Any<CalendarEntry>(c => c.Date.Date == date.Date && Filters.Any<Type>(f => typeof(c).IsInstanceOfType(f)));
```

Does anyone know why this is not working? and if I can get it to work?

Thanks.

EDIT:

Still now know why it doesn't work as I wrote it initially, but it works when I write it like this:

```
Filters.Any<Type>(f => this.Calendar.Entries.Where<CalendarEntry>(c => c.Date.Date == date.Date).SingleOrDefault().GetType().IsInstanceOfType(f));
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`typeof`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58918ffs.aspx) *only* applies to type names. If you need the run-time type of `c`, you must use [`Object.GetType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gettype.aspx) and say `c.GetType()`.

So, the compiler sees `typeof(c)` and knows that `typeof` only accepts type names and is therefore trying *valiantly* to find [a type named `c`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Boy_Named_Sue) somewhere, anywhere but, alas, it can't. So, it's telling you "I can't find the type `c`."